# Why is LiveLiteralsKt causing runtime problem?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a library that I created in one project and then copied the aar to a second project. The first project contains an app that uses the library, which builds and runs perfectly. The second project is a super basic one-activity-app that does nothing but try to display one of the UI components defined in the library. It builds but at runtime I get...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/runtime/internal/LiveLiteralKt;
    at com.mycompany.vision.ui.components.LiveLiterals$McButtonKt.Int$class-McButton(Unknown Source:0)
```

McButton is a button class defined in the library and instantiated in the main xml.

I have no idea what LiveLiteralsKt is or why the second project needs it. There is nothing in either build.gradle that indicates its use and almost no information online about what it is. A search in both projects for LiveLiteral finds nothing.

Has anyone seen this or have any idea where its coming from and how to resolve it?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue and the source file for at com.mycompany.domain is not even a Compose file. Adding the compose runtime back in helped, but it's not the right solution

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using live edit of literals in your first project. As I know, it is enabled by default, but may be disabled manually in corresponding menu near "code/split/design" while you are editing any file with composable functions.
Consider disabling it and recompiling the project.

Official docs:
<strike>[https://]developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/studio#live-edit-literals</strike>
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/iterative-development#live-edit

Comment: Thank You. That was a great suggestion. It didnt fix the problem but it's a reasonable guess. I also removed all of the compose stuff, which didnt help either.

Comment: Docs url seems to have moved here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/iterative-development#live-edit